# how to join list array values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

how to perform string join for array object inside list. the array may contain null values. when try with following code is show only non nullable value

```
arrError.Where(x=>x.subject != null).Select(r1 =>
                                {
                                    r1.errors_path = String.Join("_", ((IList)r1.errors_path != null ? r1.errors_path : string.Empty).OfType<string>());
                                    return r1;
                                }
             )
```

The input list structure is

```
name    age subject[]
user1   25  null
user12  26  null
user2   30  [s1,s2,s3,s4]
user3   28  [s1,s3]
```

after run linq query i want get list in following format

```
name    age subject[]
user1   25  null
user12  26  null
user2   30  s1_s2_s3_s4
user3   28  s1_s3
```

Comment: You should use the "Language-integrated-**QUERY**-Language" to **modify** items. Having said this, what speaks against some good old-style loops?

Comment: Loop is not possible,

Comment: Eeeehm, how is a loop not possible? That sounds strange to me. In fact that´s the exact same your linq-code will do under the hood.

Comment: why do you even carse for `null`? `String.Join` is well able to handle null-elements within you array.

Comment: Your `OfType` will enumerate the string return from `String.Join`. As **none** of the elements within that string itself is a string, but a `char`, your result-string is null.

Comment: what is `r1.error_path`? I suppose it´s a string. In this case with which string do you want to join it? Currently you say something like set  `r1.error_path` to `r1.error_path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.Join(String separator, params String[] value)` will thrown an exception if the `value` is null. then you need to test before using it.

can try this code :

```
arrError.Select(r1 => new 
{ 
    Name = r1.name, 
    Age = r1.age,
    subject = r1.subject != null ? string.Join("_", r1.subject) : null 
});
```

for test i used :

```
// class like your structure
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string[] Subject { get; set; }
}

// initializing the list
List<TestClass> testClasses = new List<TestClass>
{
    new TestClass{Name = "user1", Age=25, Subject = null},
    new TestClass{Name = "user132", Age=26, Subject = null},
    new TestClass{Name = "user2", Age=30, Subject = new string[]{"S1","S2","S3","S4"}},
    new TestClass{Name = "user3", Age=28, Subject = new string[]{"S1","S3"}},
};

// simulating your demand
var result = testClasses.Select(r1 => new 
{ 
    Name = r1.Name, 
    Age = r1.Age,
    Subject = r1.Subject != null ? string.Join("_", r1.Subject) : null 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var output= arrError.Select(a => new
            {
                name = a.name,
                age = a.age,
                subject = String.Join("_", a.subject)
            }).ToList();
```